# Addition in $\operatorname{GF}(2^4)$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

How can I compute $A(x)+B(x) \mod P(x)$ in $\operatorname{GF}(2^4)$ using the irreducible polynomial $P(x)=x^4+x+1$. What is the influence of the choice of the reduction polynomial on the computation?

> 1. $A(x)=x^2+1, B(x)=x^3+x^2+1$
> 2. $A(x)=x^2+1, B(x)=x+1$

Comment: you tried dividing $A+B$ by $x^4+x+1$ with usual long division thing?

Answer (score 1):

When the operands are given in their standard form (as polynomials of degree less than $n$), *addition* in $\mathrm{GF}(p^n)$ does not depend on which irreducible polynomial you use.

Just add each pair of matching coefficients and reduce it modulo $p$:

$$\begin{align} &(x^2+1)+(x^3+x^2+1) \\=&(0x^3+1x^2+0x+1)+(1x^3+1x^2+0x+1) \\=& (0+1)x^3+(1+1)x^2+(0+0)x+(1+1) \\=& 1x^3+0x^2+0x+0 \\=& x^3 \end{align}$$
because $1+1\equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

Comment: Is that for first example right?

Comment: @Tim: Sorry, that was a typo, now fixed.

Comment: and what about the A(x)=x^2+1,B(x)=x+1

Comment: @Tim: You can add those in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Addition on $GF(2^4)$ is made by adding the polynomials and reducing the coefficients mod 2. Multiplication is done by first multiplying the polynomials in the classical way (and reducing the coefficients mod 2) then reducing the degree of the polynomial to a degree at most 3 by using $x^4=-x-1=x+1$.

So in your first example,
$$
(x^2+1)+(x^3+x^2+1)=x^3 + 2x^2+2=x^3
$$
and
\begin{align}
(x^2+1)(x^3+x^2+1)&=x^5+x^4+x^2+x^3+x^2+1\\&=(x+1)x^4+x^3+1\\&=x^3+(x+1)(x+1)+1\\&=x^3+x^2+2x+2\\&=x^3+x^2
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you Ivanesbeeck. I am still stuck in the second example? Maybe you can show us a way again..

Comment: The result for the addition is wrong -- the constant term should be 0.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Exact! I'm correcting my answer right now